# Dynamically loaded control and databinding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a control on a Webpage that for reasons I can't begin to comprehend is being added dynamically(Page.LoadControl). This control basically binds various labels etc to the results of a stored procedure.

What I have had to is replicate this mechanism, but display the results of a different stored procedure instead. So, I've created the new stored proc, checked that it works, and then created a new control that can be dynamically loaded the same way...

The problem I am having is that certain fields are not displaying on the page - for instance this one...

```
<td class="col2"><asp:Label ID="CPlannedDate" text = '<%# Eval("PlannedDateTimeSlot")%>' /></td>
```

Calls to other fields work fine. I've modified the sproc to return the PlannedDateTimeSlot as a formatted varchar, and I've stuck a breakpoint where the datasource is set to check that the field is indeed populated in the underlying data source - they are.

The fields that are not displaying seem to be ones I have added on top of the original ones, but the datasource is a DataTable (not strongly typed)...

I'm been staring at this for a couple of hours and can't think what's happening - anyone got any ideas?

Ps. I should just add that further down the page, I have a label like this which isn't working either :

```
Date of Issue: <asp:Label ID="CDOI" text='<%= DateTime.Today.ToString() %>' />
```

It's almost as though the code stops trying to render dynamic content on the page after a certain point...

Comment: missing runat... Anyone got a noose?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place where people tie your noose for you. You gotta show some effort. Do you have a rope?

Comment: hah. just saw your comment now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no `runat=server` on that asp:label